# Heap corruption in code

Tags: c++, c, memory, heap-corruption

According to the Visual C++ runtime there is a heap corruption when calling free in the destructor. But I don't understand why there is a heap corruption, can anyone explain why? The precise error is:

```
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

Also, if I ignore the error the program doesn't crash, it keeps running and when I press a key it returns 0.

The class only contains a constructor and destructor and the private vars `FILE* target` and `char* raw_data`.

```
foo::foo (wchar_t* path)
{
    size_t size;

    target = _wfopen (path, L"rb+");
    if (!target) {
        char* error = strerror (errno);
        printf ("The file could not be opened: %s\n", error);
        _exit (1);
    }

    fseek (target, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell (target);
    fseek (target, 0, SEEK_SET);
    raw_data = (char*) malloc (size);
    size = fread (raw_data, 1, size, target);
    raw_data[size] = '\0';
}

foo::~foo ()
{
    fclose (target);
    free (raw_data);
}

int main ()
{
    nbt* klas = new nbt (L"C:\\Users\\Ruben\\level");
    puts ("Success?!");
    delete klas;
    getchar ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One sure problem is this code:

```
raw_data = (char*) malloc (size);
size = fread (raw_data, 1, size, target);
raw_data[size] = '\0';
```

You cannot access `raw_data[size]`, because it is beyond the allocated size. Indexed access in C/C++ is zero based. As a result, the last element of `raw_data` that can be accessed with your existing code is `raw_data[size-1]`. To be able to set the byte which is at offset `size` to zero you need to change your `malloc` to:

```
raw_data = (char*) malloc (size+1);
```

Since this is a C++ application, you may want to use streams and new/delete instead of FILE pointers and malloc/free.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. And I use malloc, since I may need to realloc the data later.

Answer (score 4):

When writing the `NUL` terminator as you do:

```
raw_data[size] = '\0';
```

... you are using one byte more than the bytes you allocated. There may be other errors but there is definitely an error on this line -- writing to memory you have not allocated is "undefined behaviour" and could explain the crash you're observing.

Comment: "if I ignore the error the program doesn't crash, it keeps running" so no crash here, but the answer still holds, maybe even more so; anything can happen when in undefined behavior land.